# VLC media player 2.2.1 is choppy

Tags: command-line, video, vlc

Ubuntu version is 14.04.1. VLC is choppy depending on how it's started. From the console window this command works fine:

```
/usr/bin/cvlc -vvv /home/matt/Hockey_Footage.m2t --sout udp:239.204.1.106:4000 --loop --ttl 15
```

I can join the MC address from a MAC and it plays fine. Of course the output commands from vlc display on the console screen, e.g. many lines like

```
[00007ffb80001e78] udp access out debug: packet has been sent too late (7313601842)
```

If I ssh to the Ubuntu server and run the exact same command, joining the MC stream from the same MAC it is choppy and pixelated. This wouldn't be an issue but I want to start two streams and haven't figured out how to do this.

I created a script called START-VIDEO-1.sh with the above command in it. If I start the script from the console, it plays fine (can join the MC stream from MAC) but vlc commands are displayed on the console, e.g.

```
[00007ffb80001e78] udp access out debug: packet has been sent too late (7313601842)
```

I have tried several combinations of redirection but haven't cracked it yet. Can anyone share/provide the best way to start vlc via a script such that no output is displayed on the console, allowing me to start two videos?